# Code snippets in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, code-snippets, webstorm, code-completion

I use PhpStorm.   I want to make snippets of code and then assign shortcuts to them. I can do it in NetBeans, but in PhpStorm I don't know how to make them.

For example, to add `console.log();` in NetBeans, I only type **con + space**. `con` is the shortcut that I had defined.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

In IntelliJ (the Java IDE) or PhpStorm (the PHP IDE) it is called Live Templates.

Go to `Setting`s and start typing `"live templates"` in the search box. On the right panel you can edit and create such templates.

So in your case, you simply type "con" in the abbreviation text box and "console.log();" in the template box text area below. You may even change, with which action you want to expand the template (Tab is default, space and enter are possible).

The live template thing is much more complex than what I wrote above. You can use variables and some context information. For further reading, I suggest the [JetBrains / PhpStorm documentation.](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html)

Comment: thank you very much. can you tell me how to change the cursor position?

Comment: What do you mean by changing the cursor position? At least in IntelliJ in the live template settings there is a checkbox to reformat, after the template has been expanded. Then the live template lines are indented.

Comment: I find out how. I use this `console.log($s$);` and then when the editor adds it the cursor moves to the position of $s$.

Comment: @AladdinHoms You can use `$END$` to specify final position where cursor will end up after all variables (like your `$s$`) are processed/filled.

Comment: As I needed more info I went to PHPStorm's help area [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html)

Comment: Remember to enable it for JavaScript. You do that by clicking `Define` in the text "No applicable contexts. Define" beneath the `Template text` box.

Comment: How can i define template `console.log` template for comma separated variables, i.e: selected text  'a, b' should be converted into  `console.log(a);<NEW LINE>console.log(b);`

Comment: On Mac, go to PhpStorm > Preferences > Live Templates - and follow the advice above (inc. enabling for the correct language)